# Entity Framework materializes collections inside IQueryable methods before their execution

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ienumerable

On my previous work EF keeps query as `IQueryable` until I used some materialized methods, for example, `ToList()` or `FirstOrDefault()`, and I could create big, flexible and fast queries. But on my new work I noted, that sequences inside `IQueryable` methods have `ICollection` type and, of course, they have `IEnumerable` methods (not `IQueriable`). I can't understand what wrong and how I can change it. I haven't find solution in google. The version of EF is the same as on my previous work (6.1.3).

For Example, I have 2 entity classes and my own class:

```
public class Client // Entity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Parcel> ParcelsSender { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Parcel> ParcelsReceiver { get; set; }
}

public class Parcel // Entity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ParcelNumber { get; set; }
    ...
    public int ClientSenderID { get; set; }
    public int ClientReceiverID { get; set; }
    public virtual Client ClientSender { get; set; }
    public virtual Client ClientReceiver { get; set; }
}

public class ClientCustom // My class
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public bool IsInexperienced { get; set; }
}
```

and I created this EF query:

```
var clients = context.Clients
    .OrderBy(x => x.FullName)
    .Select(x => new ClientCustom()
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        FullName = x.FullName,
        IsInexperienced = x.ParcelsSender.Select(y => y.ID).FirstOrDefault() == 0 
            && x.ParcelsReceiver.Select(y => y.ID).FirstOrDefault() == 0
    })
    .ToList();
```

In this case, the problem is that `x.ParcelsSender` and `x.ParcelsReceiver` in query are `ICollection<Parcel>` type; In turn, `x.ParcelsSender.Select()` and `x.ParcelsReceiver.Select()` methods returns `IEnumerable<Parcel>` instead `IQueriable<Parcel>`. As I know, that means, queries become very slowly with big amount of data.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Are you using code first approach or db first approach, if first approach provide some code from your DbContext here so we can see what is going on

Comment: Are you talking about collection navigation properties? You really need to show some example in order to see what's the issue (if there is an issue at all).

Comment: Seeing this question now. This is a non-issue. The whole LINQ query is translated into SQL. Voting to close as not reproducible.